# PHP code stops when it comes to $pdo->prepare

Tags: php, database, pdo, insert

I'm trying to INSERT some data into my database using PDO but it just stops after "00I AM TRYING!" and no errors are output.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $error = FALSE;

    //in here it checks for a lot of different errors that 
    //the user may have input, if there is ANY error it 
    //will set the variable $error to TRUE and will stop the code.
    //This part does work perfectly and is not the problem

    echo (int)$error;
    if ($error == FALSE) try {
        echo (int)$error;
        echo 'I AM TRYING!';
        $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (inputA, inputB, inputC, inputD, inputE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)');
        echo (int)$error = FALSE;
        echo 'IT WORKS';
        $query->bindValue(1, $inputA);
        $query->bindValue(2, $inputB);
        $query->bindValue(3, $inputC);
        $query->bindValue(4, $inputD);
        $query->bindValue(5, $inputE);

        $query->execute();

        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Exception caught: $e";
}
}
```

The output I am getting is a blank page with the following information: "00I AM TRYING!", which means the code stops after "00I AM TRYING!"

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: Not getting errors; are you checking for them, and if so, how?

Comment: Please note that `bindValue` does not escape `%` or `_` and therefore leaves you once again vulnerable to SQL injection even with prepared statements. Please consider switching to `bindParam` instead, or ensure you enforce stripping of these characters from any user input manually. Furthermore, if your query stops right there, it's because `you could not call a member function prepare on a non object` which is likely because `$pdo` wasn't setup somewhere properly. if you enable `error_reporting(0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` you will probably see that.

Comment: Add this to your PDO connection: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` and you will receive exception when you get an error.

Comment: What Sal00m meant was to add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. Also add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: if he puts the whole PDO connection in a try block he can then use what both saloom and fredii said and in the catch exception use `echo $e->getMessage()` for a easy on the eye error to show exactly where the problem is

Comment: Probably $pdo variable undefined.

Comment: Thank you, the display errors code showed the errors, was some simple things, should have thought of it earlier!

Comment: You're welcome and right on Casper, glad to hear you've found the errors, even better if you've found a solution, *cheers*